# Parameters.AddWithValue vs Parameters.Add?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle11g

I am inserting data using below code 
first why i am not able to use Parameters.AddWithValue(); ??
and what the actual difference between Parameters.AddWithValue and        Parameters.Add ???? I had made search but each one said the the other is deprecated which one is really deprecated now ?!
and what the Namespace for each one ?? as I know the using Parameters.AddWithValue is  Oracle.DataAccess; and for the Parameters.Add is using System.data.oracle;

second why I am getting below error when at this line I don't find anything wrong with it

```
using (OracleCommand cmd =new OracleCommand(cmdstr,connstr))
```

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.OracleCommand(string,
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection)' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'
>
> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection does not contain a
>   definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public void connect_to_db()
{
    string connstr = "Data Source=orcl;User Id=user;Password=pwd;";
    string cmdstr = @"insert into customers 
                      set    (CUST_NAME) 
                      values (:TB_CUST_NAME);";
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connstr))
    using (OracleCommand cmd =new OracleCommand(cmdstr,connstr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":TB_CUST_NAME", TB_CUST_NAME);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is caused because you pass your `connstr` (`string`) instead of your `conn` (`OracleConnection`). Change this:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd =new OracleCommand(cmdstr,connstr))
```

To this

```
using (OracleCommand cmd =new OracleCommand(cmdstr,conn))
```

As for the second one, the `OracleParameter` [does not seem to need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048910/oraclecommand-sql-parameters-binding) `:`. Example use:

```
OracleCommand oraCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT fullname FROM sup_sys.user_profile
                           WHERE domain_user_name = :userName", db);
oraCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("userName", domainUser));
```

It seems like there is a difference between `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` and `System.Data.OracleClient`. `OracleParameterCollection.AddWithValue` seems to exist in `System.Data.OracleClient`. But you use `Oracle.DataAccess.Client`.

Comment: the :TB_CUST_NAME is the name of the textbox i want to retrieve its data and insert it into a table so I am not using select i am using insert into and I had point to the textbox name i want to get the value from

Comment: @samer note that you do that (having `:`) in your `cmdstr` (`OracleCommand`), you don't do that in your `OracleParameter`

Comment: according to that post   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105042/inserting-textbox-values-into-database

Comment: i used that way now but i got error ORA-00911: invalid character  cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":userName", textboxuserName.Text));

Comment: Again, the : is not needed for OracleParameter. It is only for OracleCommand. Try to remove : in the OracleParameter

Comment: i did that but nothing happened just nothing  string cmdstr = @"insert into customers 
                      set    (CUST_NAME) 
                      values (:TB_CUST_NAME);";

Comment: the add parameter will be like this cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("TB_CUST_NAME", TB_CUST_NAME.Text));

Comment: @samer any error now? If there isn't, your code has at least been syntatically correct now. So, the original question is solved. As for the reason why your database is not updated, that is likely belong to another question. Maybe it is caused by wrong column name or wrong value. But you are syntatically correct now.

Comment: no error nothing happen while when I re add the : i got the  ORA-00911: invalid character I tried to get the insert string and pasted into toad and run it and data inserted

Comment: Thanks my friends and @Ian your right a f***  ; at the end of insert statment was the problem -_-"silly enough